# Print website as PDF without altering the CSS

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, css, print-to-pdf

I've updated my CV with some flashy illustrative elements that I've positioned using absolute positioning in CSS. Now I want to print/export the site as a PDF. The problem is that all absolute positioned images loses their positioning attributes when I print it.

I've searched around for a solution, tried various PDF print plugins for firefox, changing the media type in the CSS to "all"... but still no success.

Does anyone know of a solution that would do what I want? The only alternative I can think of is to distribute my CV as a HTML file but I would like to avoid that if I can (from experience I know that some recruiters are a bit conservative when it comes to formats...)

Comment: Have you tried a free PDF printer, such as [this one](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php)?

Comment: I have the same issue. I have my CV all setup in HTML and styled how I want it with CSS but I cannot find a way to export it to PDF without the styling being changed. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @webworm hmm.. don't think I did. As I recall I reverted back to saving it as a PNG, and turned the PNG into a PDF. So unfortunately no luck.
I would suggest if you have a CV as a web document that you upload it to a free hosting service and then link to it in your applications. One upside with that is that you don't have to worry about the document size (at least not the 25 Mb limited to most SP's) plus you can assure that everyone always have access to your latest version.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried  [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list). I was really satisfied with it.

It uses the webkit rendering engine that renders the `html` so as to export under `pdf`.

My final `pdf` was really close to the original `html`.

However I have not tested absolute coordinates.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip! Only problem is that I don't seem to figure out how to run it... I've tried downloading the installer and installing it, however running the installed program doesn't seem to do anything, I've downloaded the Windows Static Library, however I can't figure out how to run that either. Do you have any guiding for me perhaps...?

Comment: I found some step by step guide in the wiki, I'll get back to you!

Comment: you have to launch it by hand in the command console. cmd.exe.

Comment: yea thanks, I've come that far. problem is though that the website is a local HTML file and it's not hosted. I can't seem to find if that's supported or not.